# How can I update multiple rows in one query?

Tags: sql, firebird

How can I update multiple rows in one query?

I have something like this:

```
update POL_VYMFOND set fk_vsoub='2245'
where fk_vsoub in (select HL_VYMSOUB.ID_VSOUB
from POL_VYMSEZN
inner join HL_VYMSEZN
    on HL_VYMSEZN.ID_VSEZN=POL_VYMSEZN.FK_VSEZN
inner join HL_VYMSOUB
    on HL_VYMSOUB.FK_VSEZN=HL_VYMSEZN.ID_VSEZN
where POL_VYMSEZN.FK_BUDOVA='4')
```

but definitely wrong.

Is it possible to do this?

I would like to change column values in one table according to values from another table.

Thank you

Comment: Just add the other columns `update POL_VYMFOND set fk_vsoub='2245', other_column = 42, third_column = 'foobar' where ...`

Comment: Please be more specific as to what your problem is. Did you not know the [basic syntax of update](http://www.firebirdsql.org/file/documentation/reference_manuals/fblangref25-en/html/fblangref25-dml-update.html) to update multiple columns (see the comment by a_horse), or are you having a different problem? If so, what is that problem?

Comment: I need update one column (more cells). With this select: `select HL_VYMSOUB.ID_VSOUB from POL_VYMSEZN inner join HL_VYMSEZN on HL_VYMSEZN.ID_VSEZN=POL_VYMSEZN.FK_VSEZN inner join HL_VYMSOUB on HL_VYMSOUB.FK_VSEZN=HL_VYMSEZN.ID_VSEZN where POL_VYMSEZN.FK_BUDOVA='4'` I get several values for example: `ID 2456 1458 1454 448` and every this value I want to change to 2245

Comment: So you want to update multiple **rows** not columns? If so what is wrong with your existing query? Do you get an error, doesn't it work (if so: describe how it doesn't work), and please: edit your question, don't use comments for additions/clarifications.

Comment: try MERGE - https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Merge_(SQL)

Comment: or this http://www.firebirdsql.org/refdocs/langrefupd21-merge.html

Answer (score 4):

Generic answer for future developers.

## SQL Server

```
UPDATE 
     t1
SET 
     t1.column = t2.column
FROM 
     Table1 t1 
     INNER JOIN Table2 t2 
     ON t1.id = t2.id;
```

## Oracle (and SQL Server)

```
UPDATE 
     t1
SET 
     t1.colmun = t2.column 
FROM 
     Table1 t1, 
     Table2 t2 
WHERE 
     t1.ID = t2.ID;
```

## MySQL

```
UPDATE 
     Table1 t1, 
     Table2 t2
SET 
     t1.column = t2.column 
WHERE
     t1.ID = t2.ID;
```

## Firebird 2.1

```
UPDATE dest_table t1
SET 
field1 = (select field1 from src_table t2 where t2.pk = t1.pk),
field2 = (select field2 from src_table t2 where t2.pk = t1.pk)
WHERE EXISTS (select 1 from src_table t2 where t2.pk = t1.pk)
```

For other versions of Firebird please [check this link](http://www.firebirdfaq.org/faq323/)

Hope this will help you, and will solve your issue.

Comment: The question is about Firebird. Not for Oracle, not for SQL and not for MySQL (plus: the second UPDATE statement is **not** valid for Oracle)

Comment: The question also has SQL category.

Comment: Yes, and that refers to standard SQL - not a specific DBMS product. And there is no `FROM` in standard SQL for the `UPDATE` statement

Comment: Not work. with this 
`UPDATE POL_VYMFOND SET fk_vsoub='2245'
where exists (
select HL_VYMSOUB.ID_VSOUB
from POL_VYMSEZN
inner join HL_VYMSEZN
    on HL_VYMSEZN.ID_VSEZN=POL_VYMSEZN.FK_VSEZN
inner join HL_VYMSOUB
    on HL_VYMSOUB.FK_VSEZN=HL_VYMSEZN.ID_VSEZN
where POL_VYMSEZN.FK_BUDOVA='4')`

update every value in pol_vymfond

Comment: I think you mean firebird 2.0 :-) With 2.1 you have a MERGE statement :-) http://firebirdsql.su/doku.php?id=merge